# What was the meaning of the tunnel scene?

Tags: analysis, vanishing-on-7th-street

In Vanishing on 7th Street, people disappear if they become engulfed in darkness.  At one point Paul is lying on the pool table and the kid went to the bathroom.  The lights flicker and Paul gets up.  He ends up finding his way into this tunnel.  When he reaches the end he looks back and all of the lights go out.  The kid goes back in and finds Paul missing.

What is the meanign of the tunnel scene?  It seems that it didn't actually happen, but I'm confused as to why it's included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw this, too. My opinion was it's a flash dream like Occurance at Owl Creek Bridge. Something that feels long or extended, but only happens in a moment. And he was the one taken, not the kid

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Paul became engulfed because he imagined himself being tricked by the "Shadows".In other words he loses inside his mind.